# How to intercept Quick Find FetchXml on QueueItem entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am a CRM system administrator (CRM 2016 SP1 on-premise). I am trying to register a plugin on the queueitem entity using the RetrieveMultiple message on Pre-operation stage to be able to intercept and modify the FetchXml of the query when the user searches for records using the Quick Find bar.

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple.aspx) queueitem entity does support the RetrieveMultiple message, but when I try to register it with the entity using the Plugin Registration Tool, I get the error:

> Invalid Primary Entity or Secondary Entity

And when I register the plugin without defining the primary and secondary entities nothing happens when I search for queueitem records in any queue.

Comment: It's likely that QueueItem being a "special" entity, it doesn't support plugins

Comment: Thanks Alex. After some more digging I came into the conclusion that it's not possible to intercept the search query for queueitem records in a plugin. I hope Microsoft will implement this in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

`QueueItem` supports all other messages (`Create`/`Update`/`Delete`/`SetState`) except `Retrieve` `RetrieveMultiple`.

Ref: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx)